# Detect Foreground push click event on Firebase FCM

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I use the [firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/API.md) plugin with Ionic 4 app. I have a use case to implement when a user clicked the foreground push. i.e. he must redirect to different UI. How can I do that? I can do this with background push clicked use case.

```
fcmListeners() {
    this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(async (data: any) => {

      if (data.tap) {// when user tapped the background notification
        this.pushRedirection(data);
        console.log("Received in background-data", data);
      } else {
        console.log("Received in foreground", data);
        this.pushRedirection(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

If I use the above kind of code then it automatically goes to the desired page without the user clicked. But I need to implement it if the user clicked the push only. So can you tell me how to handle this?

Payload:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "dlaNHzi7Gy8:APA91bGdn_jXFJm1xdGGI44s48JbXEu5iYa"
  ],
  "notification": {
    "body": "Push Test Facility Category",
    "title": null,
    "icon": "myicon",
    "sound": "mySound",
    "vibrate": 1,
    "Badge": 1,
    "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "Push Test Facility Category",
    "title": null,
    "b": "22",
    "id": "2",
    "category_name": "Restaurants",
    "h": "1",
    "p": 1,
    "type": "2"
  }
}
```

`this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(async (data: any)`

[image]

**Note:** I can implement a custom notification toast here for android since it doesn't show anything on foreground notification. But iOS it shows foreground notification by default. So how to handle that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Corodva plugin currently shows the push notification even when the notification was received being the app in the foreground, but that's **[an issue](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/817#issuecomment-490871504)** and shouldn't be the default behavior. As you can see in that issue, until the fix is merged you can fix it locally like this:

> I changed
>
> `PROJECT_ROOT/plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/src/ios/AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m`
>
> but also
>
> `PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME/plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m`
>
> In both files in line 183, I replaced
>
> `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);`
>
> with
>
> `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);`
>
> Now, it behaves like expected (no notification in foreground, only in
>   background)

After fixing that, you can use `data.tap` and should work properly:

```
if (data.tap) {
  // when user tapped the background notification
  this.pushRedirection(data);
  console.log("Received in background-data", data);
}
```

---

If you need to do this in an CI/CD environment or you just want to automate it, you can create a **[Cordova Hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/)**.

In order to do this, first create a new `cordova-hooks` folder in `src` and then create a new js file named `fix_push-notifications-foreground_issue.js` like this:

```
src
 |- ...
 |- cordova-hooks
      |- fix_push-notifications-foreground_issue.js
 |- node_modules
 |- ...
```

Please notice that there are some other ways to add Cordova hooks (like using the default `hooks` folder) but still I prefer to use a custom folder. More information can be found **[here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/)**.

Paste the following code in that new js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
module.exports = function (context) {

    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    const issue = `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);`;
    const fix = `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);`;

    // ISSUE: iOS: Push notifications are shown when in foreground
    // https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/817

    function start() {
        console.log('+------------------------------------+');
        console.log('| Starting PN Foreground Fix Hook    |');
        console.log('+------------------------------------+');


        const pluginDir = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, '/plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/src/ios');
        const pluginFile = path.join(pluginDir, 'AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m');

        const platformPluginDir = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, '/platforms/ios/YourAppName/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib');
        const platformPluginFile = path.join(platformPluginDir, 'AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m');

        applyFixToFile(pluginFile);
        applyFixToFile(platformPluginFile);

        console.log('+------------------------------------+');
    }

    /**
     * Fixes the push notification foreground issue on the file sent as parametner
     * @param {*} file Path of the file to be fixed
     */
    function applyFixToFile(file) {
        if (fs.existsSync(file)) {
            let content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString('utf8');

            if (content.indexOf(issue) > -1) {

                content = content.replace(issue, fix);
                fs.writeFileSync(file, content);

                console.log(`   PN foregorund fix applied to ${file} file`);

            } else {

                console.log(`   No need to apply PN foreground fix to ${file} file`);

            }

        } else {
            console.log(`   Unable to find ${file} file`);
        }
    }

    // Start the hook
    start();

}
```

And finally, add the hook in your `config.xml` file:

```
<widget ...

  <hook src="cordova-hooks/fix_push-notifications-foreground_issue.js" type="before_prepare" />

  <platform name="android">
  ...
  </platform>

  <platform name="ios">
  ...
  </platform>

</widget>
```

Now every time you build the app, the fix should be applied automatically :)

Comment: Oh.. You have shown me a different path here. Yes, according to the doc it must not have toast notification on the foreground. But my client needs it a notification there too. But I can do this kind of thing then since now I can disable the default iOS toast. i.e. I can implement custom toast with buttons and then according to the button selection where I can redirect the user to relevant UI no? Note: I can handle this with the background. No issues there.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to disable the default toast of the notification, and use an Ionic toast or any other UI element to show to the user. Since the default toast is not shown, `data.tap` will be true only if the app was not in the foreground when the notification was received.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Great help!